# rubyonrailsをdocker-composeで実行したい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose

GCPインスタンスで
[DockerでRails + MySQLの開発環境をつくる手順](https://qiita.com/jshimazu/items/ba13ce87dfdb11e2d1d9)
やITエンジニアになるDocker仮想化環境構築入門を見ると

```
docker version
Client:
 Version:           18.09.2
 API version:       1.39
 Go version:        go1.10.6
 Git commit:        6247962
 Built:             Sun Feb 10 04:13:27 2019
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          18.09.2
  API version:      1.39 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.10.6
  Git commit:       6247962
  Built:            Sun Feb 10 03:47:25 2019
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
```

```
docker-compose version
docker-compose version 1.17.1, build 6d101fb
```

```
Dockerfile
FROM ruby:2.4.2
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev nodejs
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
ADD Gemfile /app/Gemfile
ADD Gemfile.lock /app/Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install
ADD . /app
```

```
Gemfile
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '5.1.4'
```

Gemfile.lockを作り

`docker-compose run web rails new . --force --database=mysql`

行ったんですが
ローカルにはrailsのプロジェクトが新規に作成されていません。
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root  85 Feb 19 20:56 .
dr-xr-x---. 4 root root 132 Feb 19 20:56 ..
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 379 Feb 19 20:56 docker-compose.yml
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 235 Feb 19 20:49 Dockerfile
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  66 Feb 19 20:51 Gemfile
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   0 Feb 19 20:51 Gemfile.lock
このように表示されています。
何が原因なんでしょうか？
config/database.ymlを行いたいです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dockerfileですがappでは無くmyappでは無いでしょうか。

```
FROM ruby:2.4.2
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev nodejs
RUN mkdir /myapp
WORKDIR /myapp
ADD Gemfile /myapp/Gemfile
ADD Gemfile.lock /myapp/Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install
ADD . /myapp
```